# Routed events in uwp

Tags: uwp, event-bubbling, routed-events

I'm having difficulty finding how to register a RoutedEventHandler in UWP. I need to have an event handler in parent class which can control access to all child classes inside it.

Answer (score 1):

Currently UWP cannot customize routing events like WPF. In UWP, you can consider using `EventHandler` instead of `RoutedEventHandler`:

```cs
public class ParentModel
{
    public event EventHandler TestEvent;

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //do other things...

        TestEvent?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```cs
var parent = new ParentModel();
parent.TestEvent += HandleTest;

...

private void HandleTest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var parent = sender as ParentModel;
    // do something...
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I have so many click events to be handled inside my parent class. So is there any other alternative like bubbling in WPF so that I can have only one event handler in the parent class and can get control from all child classes

Comment: The Click event is a direct route event, which only acts on the Button itself, and will not continue to bubble upwards. If you want to pass the Button click event out of the parent class, you still need to add `EventHandler` and Invoke in the `Button_Click` event